# How to output variables dynamically in ColdFusion

Tags: dynamic, properties, coldfusion, replace

I am trying to replace a value with a passed value using javascript or coldfusion. The idea is we have a template which outputs values in the grid. But the values displayed need be dynamically determined by a query. So far I haven't been able to come up with any good ideas.

Here is a sample of something I thought would of work (but does not). It may explain what I am trying to do:

```
<cfset StaticValue="DynamicValue">

<cfset DynamicValue="What I Want To Show">

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<cfoutput>#StaticValue#</cfoutput>";
</script>

<cfoutput>#<span id="demo"></span>#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand this right.  Is the Dynamic Value to replace the Static value in response to some event?  How is the dynamic value being passed in?  Is this coming from an ajax call to some serverside cf?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: you don't need the outputs around the span tag. Remove them and the code above should work... though you may need to add a function or behavior. The code above seems useless - might as well put your "dynamic value" in between the span tags like <span id="demo"><cfoutput>#dynamicValue#</cfoutput></span> ... I assume you have something behavioral in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an existing string/variable as a variable name, you need to use bracket notation.

In CF, if you haven't explicitly scoped a variable, it is created in the `Variables` scope, so you can do:

```
<cfset StaticValue="DynamicValue">

<cfset DynamicValue="What I Want To Show">

<!--- outputs value of Variables.DynamicValue --->
<cfoutput>#Variables[StaticValue]#</cfoutupt>
```

*(This works will all scopes/structs/queries/etc)*

**NOTE:** If the variable is to be output inside of a JavaScript string, you need to wrap it in `JsStringFormat(...)` to ensure the appropriate characters are escaped.

Comment: .. and since you mentioned something about queries, note that they can also be accessed with bracket notation. ie `queryName[columnName][rowNumber]`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is wrong:

```
<cfoutput>#<span id="demo"></span>#</cfoutput>
```

You are suggesting that there is a CF variable named

```
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Your question isn't clear, so neither can be my answer, but I suspect that you are trying to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <cfoutput>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="#StaticValue#";
    </cfoutput>
</script>

<span id="demo"></span>
```

When this JavaScript runs on the page, the string "DynamicValue" will be written into the span#demo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare if they are the same and then display it if they are?

```
<cfset StaticValue="DynamicValue"> 

<cfif staticvalue is dynamicvalue>
   <cfset DynamicValue="What I Want To Show"> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
   <cfoutput>
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="#DynamicValue#"; 
   </cfoutput>
   </script> 
</cfif>
```

Not sure what u are trying to do here - as this will error on bad variable inside your `#` `#`

```
<cfoutput>#<span id="demo"></span>#</cfoutput>
```

Should be:

```
<cfoutput>
<span id="demo">
#dynamicvalue#
</span>
</cfoutput>
```

If you are just trying to get a url to display:

```
<cfoutput>
<span id="demo">
<a href="#dynamicvalue#">#dynamicvalue#</a>
</span>
</cfoutput>
```